# C# google people api, peopleRequest missing PersonFields attribute

Tags: c#, google-api, google-people-api

Im trying to learn google Person api for developing application.

Im using the google api tutorial 
https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started

```
    using Google;
    using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
    using Google.Apis.People.v1;
    using Google.Apis.People.v1.Data;
    using Google.Apis.Services;

    ...

            static void Main(string[] args)
             {
                // Create OAuth credential.
                UserCredential credential = 
    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
                        ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
                    },
                    new[] { "profile", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" },
                     "me",
                    CancellationToken.None).Result;

            // Create the service.
            var peopleService = new PeopleService (new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "APP_NAME",
            });

PeopleResource.ConnectionsResource.ListRequest peopleRequest =
    peopleService.People.Connections.List("people/me");
peopleRequest.PersonFields = "names,emailAddresses";
ListConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse = peopleRequest.Execute();
IList<Person> connections = connectionsResponse.Connections;
```

When i use the example script in the tutorial, the information is retrived ok.

I created a soultion in visual studio using c#. 
I addon referance to all google api needed.

The project dont compile becuse PersonFields is not recognize. 
This attribute is requierd for the acction to success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've had the same problem and after hours destroying my brain trying to solve it, I found something close to a solution.

```
peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField
```

with values like this :

```
peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField = "person.names";
```

("names" alone doesn't work, "person.names" does)

With this I manage not to have compiling errors and an answer, the only thing that gives me a lot of pain is that according to the documentation, this is deprecated...

Hoping that google will update the API soon, and that this can help you !!

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problems. After hours of playing around I figured out **NOT** to use the `People.v1` namespace (as you do in your code sample) but the `PeopleService.v1` namespace. That is not what the Google Documentation says explicitly (it doesn't say very much at all) and for the time being I'm not quite shure what the reason behind these different namespaces is. Would love to find some clarification ...

Answer (score 1):

This I fount and work.

```
        peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField = new List<string>() {
            "person.phoneNumbers" ,
            "person.EmailAddresses",
            "person.names"
        };

        ListConnectionsResponse people = peopleRequest.Execute();

        if (people != null && people.Connections != null && people.Connections.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var person in people.Connections)
            {
                Console.Write(person.Names != null ? (person.Names[0].DisplayName + "  " ?? "n/a") : "n/a  ");
                Console.Write(person.EmailAddresses?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value + "  ");
                Console.WriteLine(person.PhoneNumbers?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
            }

            if (people.NextPageToken != null)
            {
                GetPeople(service, people.NextPageToken);
            }
```